# can't switch between scrolls - listView inside ScrollView android

Tags: android, android-listview, touch-event, android-scrollview

i have a layout with scrollview and inside it, a listview. 
While on touch, i want to be able to switch between those 2 scrolls, but for some reason, when i'm in the ScrollView, i can't switch it to the listView's build-in scroll.

I've tried using this method(and a lot like it) : http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/handle-scrollable-views-or-controls-in-another-scrollview-in-android/, but it fails to switch between the scrolls.

So, i tried another method - i'm performing touch event on a layout, and i use touch event on this layout and send on touch event to the specific item(listview or scroll), but even though the inner if is called, the ontouch of listView isn't being performed.

here's my layout :

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pull_up_main_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pull_up_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="show layout"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/touch_interceptor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the code :

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) _view.findViewById(R.id.scroll_list);
final ScrollView mainScroll = (ScrollView) _view.findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
final RelativeLayout touchInterceptor = (RelativeLayout) _view.findViewById(R.id.touch_interceptor);

touchInterceptor.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{
    float   lastY   = -1;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        //change 116 size to not a fixed size.
        if (lastY > event.getY() && mainScroll.getScrollY() == 116 && listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 && listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() <= 0)
        {
            //even though we arrive here, there's no change in the focus, and still, mainScroll is the chosen scroll.
            listView.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        else
        {
            mainScroll.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        lastY = event.getY();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: **Never** put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. The `ListView` has already a built-in `ScrollView`, so why to declare another one?

Comment: I'm well aware of that, but i absolutely need that.

Comment: Why would you absolutely need that? As the `ScrollView` has infinite height you can use a simple layout like `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation to achieve the same. The only difference: Some other `View`s may get invisible this way, but if you take them out of that `ScrollView` and into its parents layout, they remain visible, too.